# workaround FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT behaviour

Tags: android

I have defined a service that issues notifications when an event occurs. I add the notification id as an extra in the intent so that, when the user opens the app through the notification, i can retrieve the id in the activity and cancel the specific notification.

The problem is that, if there are multiple notifications visible in the drawer at any time, all of them end up with the same `Extra` value. This is because of the `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` behaviour. It will update the extras of any existing matching Intents with the new `Extra`. So now i cannot retrieve the correct notification id to cancel it.

Is there a way to work around this so that the previous `Intents` retain their `Extra` value.

According to the doc :

`public static final int FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
Added in API level 3
Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.`

Service onStartCommand() :

```
int notificationId = getId();
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
contentIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_APP, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.getContext())
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("text")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent);    
notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());
```

In the Activity's onCreate() :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            int notificationId = bundle.getInt(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
            if(notificationId != 0){
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to have a unique request code for every PendingIntent. You can reuse the notification id itself. We can set an action for the intent as well, so that the activity can recognize the intent. So change the code to :

Service onStartCommand() :

```
public static final String ACTION_NOTIFIED = "ACTION_NOTIFIED"; //added
int notificationId = getId();
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
contentIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
contentIntent.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFIED);//added
PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);//changed
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.getContext())
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("text")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent);    
notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());
```

In the Activity's onCreate() :

```
if(getIntent().getAction().equals(AppService.ACTION_NOTIFIED)){//added
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(bundle != null){
                int notificationId = bundle.getInt(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
                if(notificationId != 0){
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }
        }//added
```